Docker compose secondary IP for macvlan container
Left field question, I want to give a docker two IPs on the one macvlan network.
Problem I've encountered is I'm not sure its feasible.
the docker network segment only takes one ipv4_address entry and that entry must be a string.
You can't list the docker network twice either.
So has anyone managed this? is it at all feasible? or do I need to assign the secondary IP inside the docker with the ip addr command? (assuming it can, which initial testing shows not supported :/ )
sample composes I've tried:
networks:
   docker_network:
     ipv4_address: 
       - 10.0.0.1
       - 10.0.0.2


networks:
   docker_network:
     ipv4_address: 10.0.0.1
   docker_network:
     ipv4_address: 10.0.0.2

Thanks in advance for any insights.
